# pyodbc.Error: ('07002', '[07002] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Too few parameters. Expected 9. (-3010) (SQLExecDirectW)')

Tags: python, python-3.x, ms-access

```
conn = pyodbc.connect(r'Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=D:/flame/meysam.accdb;')
cursor_2 = conn.cursor()

cursor_2.execute('''
                INSERT INTO normal (data_norm_x1, data_norm_x2, data_norm_x3,data_norm_t1,data_norm_t2,data_norm_t3,data_norm_d1,data_norm_d2,data_norm_d3)
                VALUES(norm_x1, norm_x2,norm_x3,norm_t1,norm_t2,norm_t3,norm_d1,norm_d2,norm_d3)

              ''')

conn.commit()
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply pass your Python values into SQL using parameters. Remember SQL is a special purpose that is layered in a general purpose language like Python. The two layers do not naturally talk to each others' environments so we must pass in or receive data by interfacing with a DB-API like `pyodbc`.

Specifically, Access SQL does not know what the 9 *norm* variables you use in `VALUES` clause. Consequently, it errs out on missing parameters. So pass parameters accordingly to `?` placeholders.

```
# PREPARED STATEMENT WITH Q MARK PLACEHOLDERS
sql = """INSERT INTO normal (data_norm_x1, data_norm_x2, data_norm_x3,
                             data_norm_t1, data_norm_t2, data_norm_t3, 
                             data_norm_d1, data_norm_d2, data_norm_d3)
         VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
      """

# RUN ACTION QUERY AND BIND TUPLE OF PARAMS TO SQL
cursor_2.execute(sql, (norm_x1, norm_x2, norm_x3, 
                       norm_t1, norm_t2, norm_t3, 
                       norm_d1, norm_d2, norm_d3)
                )
conn.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it.

```
# insert data into 2 fields in a table    
import pyodbc

conn = pyodbc.connect(r'Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=C:\\your_path\\Test.accdb;')
cursor = conn.cursor()

cursor.execute(''' INSERT INTO Table1 (ID, Initials)
                    VALUES(1, 'RMS')  ''')

conn.commit()
```